# What does canvas.delete() do?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use `canvas.create_rectangle()` to draw a rectangle and assign the drawn item to a `specifier`. But after I delete the item using `canvas.delete(specifier)`, I can still run `canvas.delete(specifier)` successfully without causing error. May I know what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to really know *why?* since that's not documented anywhere (that I know of).

It's just a design decision made by the authors of `tkinter`: i.e. It is not considered an error if no items match. My guess is that since the intent is to get rid of something, whether or not it was there beforehand isn't important.

If knowing whether it is or not does matter in your situation, you could use the `Canvas.find_all()` method  first and see if the list it returns is empty.

Comment: The same goes for all(?) other canvas methods. They never raise errors on 'wrong' identifiers, not even the methods that return information about the item.  For example when using a deleted or otherwise unknown identifier `canvas.type` returns `None` and `canvas.itemcget` returns an empty string.

Comment: Thanks! That answer my question!

Comment: `Canvas.type()` returns a string when it succeeds, so getting `None` from it indicates when the specifier wasn't found. As for `Canvas.itemcget()` returning an empty string when that happens: I agree that isn't very helpful since you can't tell whether that's the value of the configuration option or it's because a matching specifier wasn't found—unless you know the option can never be that. But, as I mentioned in my answer, you can probably workaround issues like this by calling `.find_all()` (or apparently `.type()`) first to determine whether `itemcget()` is going to return meaningful data.

Comment: @martineau Yeah I agree that `find_all` is very useful to check whether the identifier exists if you're not sure. My comment was mainly meant as an addition to your answer in that not only the `delete` method but all canvas methods do not generate errors when given an unknown identifier.